# Is black hole really powerful than light from a star?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, black-holes, speed-of-light

Light from a star is so powerful energy that it travels large distances in vaccum.

Blackhole is so powerful that it can attract light. If a star is near a blackhole, the blackhole would completely suck the light out of it.

If blackhole is really that powerful, then why doesn't it work beyond the range of light?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of misunderstandings here.

> Light from a star is so powerful energy that it travels large
> distances in vaccum.

Any photon, whether from a star or from the dimmest candle, can travel infinitely far in vacuum.

> If a star is near a blackhole, the blackhole would completely suck the
> light out of it.

A BH does not suck light from a star. Instead, light that gets close to the event horizon will be strongly deflected. If it gets close enough, it may even circle around the BH. However, any mass will deflect light. Eddington first proved the deflection of light by gravity in 1918, by observing stars near the sun during an eclipse. Astronomers now routinely see light from extremely distant galaxies, that has been deflected by the "gravitational lensing" effect of nearby galaxies or clusters.

> If blackhole is really that powerful, then why doesn't it work beyond
> the range of light?

The effects of gravity, whether from a BH or from a pebble, extend to infinity. However, as Newton first stated, the effect reduces with the square of the distance.  That's why an apple falls to the ground, instead of to the much larger sun.

Finally, the range of light, like that of gravity, is infinite.